# Undoing list comprehension and turning it in nested for loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension

Does anyone know how I can turn the following list comprehension into two nested for loops? When I try and do it I get errors.

```
data_list = [self.y[a][b] for a in range(side_1, side_2) for b in range(corner_1, corner_2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
data_list = []
for a in range(side_1, side_2):
    for b in range(corner_1, corner_2):
        data_list.append(self.y[a][b])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to iterate over every row / column index pair, you should use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as a more concise solution than a nested `for` loop:

```py
from itertools import product

result = []
for a, b in product(range(side_1, side_2), range(corner_1, corner_2)):
    result.append(self.y[a][b])
```